# Rename Parallels Shared Folder

Tags: parallels

I need to rename the default folder "Parallels Shared Folders" to "anything"

I tried the Parallels settings and don't succeed.

**Why do I need this?**
I'm working on a project that does not allow folders to have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "parallels shared folders" is just a symlink to an actual mount location, which might reside in `/media`. On my system the following command shows the actual location:

```
➜  ~ readlink -f Desktop/Parallels\ Shared\ Folders 
/media/psf
```